# `require()` converts the string literal "true" to the boolean true

Tags: node.js, json, require

I have the following mapping in a JSON file:

```
"mapping": [
 {
  "true": "some string"
 },
 {
  "false": "some other string"
 }
]
```

In such a mapping, the keys are always strings. That's why I need the keys to be strings, even though, in this case, they are string representations of the boolean values.

When I load this JSON file with `require(myfile.json)`, the keys are somehow converted to actual boolean values.

Is that a bug in `require()`? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: `console.log(require('./test.json')['true']);` where test.json contains `{"true": "some string"}` works just fine.

Comment: I don't think it does that. `mapping.true` and `mapping['true']` should still work, but the quotes on key names may be skipped when the object is formatted for logging in the console, as these are not rquired on an actual JS object, only on JSON (particular string representation of an object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a `require` thing. Javascript allows to use any item as object keys, but then under the hood calls `toString` when saving or retrieving the item. For instance:

```
const a = {};
a[true] = 'value from true';
a[{somekey: 'somevalue'}] = 'value from object';
Object.getKeys(a); // ["true", "[object Object]"]
```

So your problem is related to the way javascript handles object keys. There is no way to discriminate between `true` and `'true'` when storing a value in an object key:

```
a = {};
a[true] = 'from plain true';
a["true"] = 'from stringified true';
a[true]; //  "from stringified true". See how the second assignation messes with the first, even if we are using the boolean true value as key.
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: I see, so the problem musts be somewhere else.